# Unity: Faux Gravity - inner Capsule/ Cylinder

Tags: unity-game-engine, gravity, cylindrical

I'm struggling with false Gravity in a Cylinder or Capsule. Basically I thought I could take the same Code as for spherical gravity, which does not work. So I changed some lines to get a better result.

```
    [SerializeField] float gravity = 10;

public void Attract ( Transform target )
{
    Vector3 gravityUp = (target.position - new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y,target.position.z)).normalized;
    Vector3 bodyDown = -target.up;

    Rigidbody rb = target.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    rb.AddForce(gravityUp * gravity);

    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(bodyDown, gravityUp) * target.rotation;
    targetRotation.x = 0;

    target.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(target.rotation, targetRotation, 30.0f * Time.deltaTime);

}
```

This worked OK on the first try. But the Player(target) can't rotate one the  Y-Axis. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I tried the following.

```
 Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(bodyDown, gravityUp) * target.rotation;
targetRotation.x = 0;

target.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(target.rotation, targetRotation, 30.0f * Time.deltaTime);
```

Now I use the Surface normal to rotate the Player.

```
if (Physics.Raycast(attractedBody.transform.position + attractedBody.transform.forward, -attractedBody.transform.up, out hit, distance))
    {
        surfaceNorm = hit.normal;
    }
```

But without Rigidbody Contrains the Player starts rotating without any Input. So I have to use:

```
rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
```

This works.